# meteorite-like impact of a drop of yogurt

Tags: fluid-dynamics, meteorites

When I throw a drop of [Yogurt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogurt) (through spoon) into a dish of Yogurt, it caused something like a meteor hitting the earth and something occurs similar to the place a meteor hitting the earth([Barringer Crater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barringer_Crater)).
(stable for a few seconds).

[image: meteor impact]
<sub>(source: [panoramio.com](http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/11624841.jpg))</sub>

How to explain this process through fluid dynamics?

Is there an equation to explain this fluid dynamical process?

[image: meteor splashes]
<sub>(source: [zaleski at www.lmm.jussieu.fr](http://www.lmm.jussieu.fr/%7Ezaleski/fig/splashnew.jpg))</sub>

(**Note:** sometimes the [impact of a meteorite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_event) is referred to as splashing, if small bits of ejecta are formed.)

What is The Physics of a Splash?

Comment: Where did you get the last image from? I suspect if you could fully answer this question, you might be in the running for a [Clay Mathematics Institute Prize](http://www.claymath.org/millenium-problems/navier%E2%80%93stokes-equation)

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance

"Where did you get the last image from?"
that is a single shot of a computer simulation

Comment: From what software? That's fantastically impressive!

Comment: Fluids typically follow the [Navier-Stokes equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier–Stokes_equations), so there's your yogurt example. However, rocks aren't fluids so we can't use that there. Thus, I'd argue that different principles apply here & the two ought not be compared. You may be interested in [this earlier question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93717).

Comment: @KyleKanos While rocks aren't fluid in our everyday energies, it's perfectly plausible that they might display fluid-like properties in higher energies...
I guess one could compute the relevant Reynolds number to find out :)

Comment: @BeastRaban "it's perfectly plausible that they might display fluid-like properties in higher energies"
Finally, someone who speaks English!.
It's good to meet you, :)

Comment: This seems to fall under "granular media". Looks like @BeastRaban is [quite right](http://iusti.polytech.univ-mrs.fr/~pouliquen/publiperso/annrev08.pdf).  The ground, like yogurt, is basically a shear-thinning fluid. So it gets stuck as a crater when the energy starts to dissipate.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking... The explanation through fluid dynamics is that yogurt (and the Earth at really large impact velocities) behaves like a fluid. The explanation is simply that **these may be modeled as a fluid because they obey the equations of fluid dynamics**.

Comment: So at high temperatures, rock becomes fluid which leads to some of the interesting behavior in meteorite impacts.  There has been a lot of interesting work on water drops falling into a glass of water etc.  Leo Kadanoff has done some fun stuff with this type of experiment.  [Here](http://president.uchicago.edu/page/2000-nora-and-edward-ryerson-lecture) are some neat examples.

Comment: In college, living on the 4th floor, one time when a friend was approaching, I dropped one of those 2 lb jugs of peanut butter from the window - not on top of him, he was just approaching.   I yelled "hey frank, catch", which he didn't, he just watched, but he said the plastic container of peanut butter hit the sidewalk and the peanut butter flew out upwards like it was water, about 4 feet high in a pretty spout.   That doesn't have much to do with your question, but it's what your question made me think of.  Everything becomes a fluid at high enough pressure, pretty much.

Answer (score 4):

You have three questions here

**1. "How to explain this process through fluid dynamics?**"

There is a study from "Hasson and Peck", 1964, which explains "Thickness distribution in a sheet formed by impinging jets." It's all basically Bernoulli's equation; "Velocity -> pressure -> velocity" and then simply continuity.

[image]

Shortly, With ideal fluid the Kinetic energy can be completly maintained, though there is obviously more or less 90-degree change in direction. Anouther good source is the Book "Zhang, Zhengji, Freistrahlturbinen" You can luckily preview these particular pages (53-54) here; 
http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540707714
It's german, but the equations and a picture is there.

**2. Is there an equation to explain this fluid dynamical process?**

Yes. After answering this question; [Height of Water 'Splashing'](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203753/height-of-water-splashing/) I realized that it's only [Bernoulli's principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle)

Velocity + Elevation + Pressure = Constant

At the impact, you have a point where;

- Elevation = 0
- Velocity = 0
- Pressure = all Energy

Which then has no difference compared to any explosion. The pressure is simply released to the easiest direction, and the matter influenced by this pressure will gain velocity. the direction of this velocity is defined similarily as the hydraulic pressure gradient; allways perpendicular to surface.

**3. What is the Physics of a Splash?**

Velocity - > Pressure -> Velocity to the least pressure direction. 
 -Bernoulli; that's all.