# Horizontal splash distance of water

Tags: experimental-physics

I just want to know, can we somehow derive an expression for the splash distance of water (horizontally) if we drop a ball in to a pool of water and aim to measure the maximum distance the water has splashed by?

I feel like the vertical distance of splash height there might be some connection with energy conservation or conservation of momentum to find the height ( i have found good information here infact [Height of Water 'Splashing'](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203753/height-of-water-splashing)) , but I am not sure if we can mathematically find the distance of the distance stashed horizontally?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: If you have the height of water splashing, you model the drops as projectiles following a parabolic path, and you assume one of the two possible angles that would lead to that height, you could derive the horizontal distance, Right?

Comment: But how do i measure the angle ? Do i actually have to experimentally measure it?