# What is the relation between a object and the height of the water splash?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, collision

I did some experiment between the mass of an object and the height of the water splash, the experiment is dropping a sphere object with a different mass increase by 25g, I did 4 different variables which is 25g, 50g, 75g, and 100g. The relationship seems to be linear but also like a curve graph. Is there any scientific paper that did a similar experiment before? Or the certain theory that can give me the answer

Comment: "The relationship seems to be linear but also like a curve graph." --- curve but linear? I don't understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Height of Water 'Splashing'](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203753/)