# deformation and displacement by a collison?

Tags: energy, momentum

In an experiment by Emilie du chatelet metal balls were dropped from a height on a clay bed only to find that the displacement of the clay material was proportional to the square of velocity of the ball and the depression of the clay bed was linearly proportional to the velocity of the ball. Does depression here mean depth ? 
Also Emilie reasoned the above facts by proposing that depression was due to potential energy and displacement due to kinetic energy ?

In an earlier experiment Willem Gravesande showed that the depth was proortional to square of velocity so it makes no sense to say that by depression emilie meant depth . Or was willems experiment proved false ?

In another incident newton says that the material displaces by the ball will depend on its momentum and it will essentially displace the same amout of material as equal to its mass.

Are all these above views contradictory to one another ?

And can you please say which of the above views for depth and material displaced are corret and please back it with a mathametical explanation ?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/238369/2451

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because he double-posted the identical question

Comment: that question is essentially different from this one .

Comment: Hi Faiz, while your two questions aren't identical they are so closely related that they are effectively duplicates of each other. Note that there have already been related questions on this site and you should check them.

Comment: i have checked most of them but they talk about diameters and my question is about depth

Comment: Diameter of object would be related to the depth of the hole, no?

Comment: @kale
absolutely , but i dont have ny equations