# If Burj Khalifa falls from 2m height, will there be a dent?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision, estimation

I got this question from my son, if [Burj Khalifa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burj_Khalifa) would suddenly fall from 2m height, how big would the dent be, if any? Of course we have to work with approximations. I found out that the weight of Burj Khalifa is about 500,000 tons. Physics was long time ago, but maybe it's a fun exercise for you guys.

Comment: Shall we consider the building as a punctual body?

Comment: No, it's not a "fun exercise" at all. As such, with the information you provided it's basically answerable. It's a complex inelastic collision problem that lacks so much information/data to even have a roughly approximate solution. So "thanks but no thanks" from me! :-)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195336/25301 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93717/25301

Comment: @Gert I suppose you mean that this is unanswerable?

Comment: @KyleKanos: ooopsie, yes unanswerable, of course. Thanks and my bad!

Comment: Now I see that the question may seem like a homework to some, but it's really not. I just get questions like this from my 10-year old all the time and well, of course I don't want to disappoint him telling that I don't know :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Crater

> If Burj Khalifa falls from 2m height, will there be a dent?

Yes. And **my guess is $3$ m**.

There are [multiple crater scaling laws](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/195397/75633), valid for different projectile speed ranges and ground properties, but the paper [Projectile-shape dependence of impact craters in loose granular media](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.68.060301) ([arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0309161), [e-print 1](http://www.pa.ucla.edu/sites/default/files/files/REU/Papers%202003/katie_newhall.pdf), [e-print 2](http://www.physics.uwo.ca/~debruyn/pdfs/simon_shapes_PRE.pdf)) considers the similar situation of heavy cylinders falling upright on sand-like ground and provides an equation (Eq. 4) for the dent (crater) depth:

$$ d = 0.139\sqrt{\frac{m}{\rho_g}} \frac{H^{1/3}}{\mu A^{5/12}}, $$

where $m$ is the mass of the falling object, $A$ its base area, $\rho_g$ the ground density (supposed to be a loose granular material such as sand), $\mu\approx\tan{\theta_0}$ is the coefficient of static friction of the ground grains, where $\theta_0$ is its [angle of repose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_repose), and $H$ is the height of the fall.

Supposing that the ground is sand and using

- $H =2$ m,
- $m = 45 \cdot 10^7$ kg,
- $\rho_g = 1590$ kg/m$^3$,
- $\mu=\tan{38^\circ}\approx 0.78$,
- $A = 5600$ m$^2$,

yields $d=3.3$ m.

---

### Collapse

Another interesting question, also raised in the comments, is whether the building deforms significantly in this experiment. I'd say it doesn't significantly $-$ unless it collapses. Does it?

If we consider the movement from the height $H=2$ m to the bottom of the crater, at $d = 3.3$ m, we have a change in potential energy $\Delta U = -mg(H+d)$ and no net change in kinetic energy, so the resisting force of the ground do work $W = -F_gd =-\Delta U$, leading, supposing constant force, to

$$ F_g = \frac{H+d}{d}mg \approx 1.6 mg, $$

so that $F_{\mathrm{res}} = F_g-mg = 0.6 mg$, which implies an acceleration $a\approx 0.6g$.

This doesn't exactly bode well for the building, since $a$ is unlikely to be constant, and its peak value might be considerable above the estimate, but it also doesn't necessarily seals its destiny.

[Safety margins](https://www.quora.com/How-big-a-margin-of-safety-do-civil-engineers-put-into-their-structure) for concrete structures should allow for at least about twice the projected load, which would mean $2g$, but that doesn't apply trivially, since this load is mostly supposed to be static.

Comparing to earthquake accelerations, values about $0.6g$ are supposed to cause [heavy damage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_ground_acceleration), though some buildings might resist $3g$ ([or even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Iwate%E2%80%93Miyagi_Nairiku_earthquake) a total, i.e., not only vertical acceleration above $4g$). Burj Khalifa is [earthquake proof](https://coderedsafety.com/blog/safety-features-in-the-worlds-highest-building-the-burj/) up to magnitude $7.0$, but magnitude doesn't translate directly into acceleration, as other factors, such as depth of the quake, are also important. For instance, a [magnitude $9.2$ earthquake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1964_Alaska_earthquake) can have peak acceleration as low as $0.18g$, while a [$6.3$ earthquake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Christchurch_earthquake) as high as $2.2g$. All in all, I can imagine it not crumbling with this fall, but, if a constant $a$ is too bad an approximation, the building chances of surviving might actually be low.

---

In time: the value for the area of the building base is a rough estimate obtained from this ground floor plan:

[image: Burj Khalifa ground floor plan]
<sub>[source 1](https://www.slideshare.net/senshots/bhurj-khalifa-net-case-study), [source 2](https://www.slideshare.net/safaamohammed5496/burj-khalifa-48217403)</sub>

Comment: @jojo, I got curious too and, rather than keep complaining about the lack of information, decided the give your question a real try.

Comment: But I guess some energy will be lost in deformation of the building

Comment: Many thanks, this rought estimate is more than enough :) Actually my son speculated the dent would be just 30cm, and I thought 2m at least. I'll show him the equation, maybe it will interest him in physics in future :)

Comment: @Rick, yes, the equation is valid for rigid bodies. I added a section in the answer considering if the building should collapse with the fall (tldr: maybe not).

Comment: @jojo, it was a fun exercise. :-)